# Difficulty understanding data over opto-diac

Tags: opto-isolator, triac, optoelectronics

I'm having difficulty understanding the data over [MOC3021](http://www.deradiobeurs.nl/GetPDF.ashx?artcode=100090021), DIAC side. 
Should I see it as with [DB3](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1689752.pdf)? So DB3's \$V_{bo}\$ (28-36V) is the same in opto-diac, and DB3's \$V_o\$ (min 5V) is the same as MOC3021 \$V_{tm}\$ (typ 1.8V max 3V) and DB3's \$I_{trm}\$ (2A) is MOC3021's \$I_{tsm}\$ (1A), all calculated from \$P_d\$ max for MOC3021:

$$ {300\text{mW}\over1\text{A}} = 300\text{mV}$$

although max 3V why

$$ 300\text{mW} \times 3\text{V} = 900\text{mA}$$

or

$$300\text{mW} \times 1.8V = 540\text{mA}$$

?

Comment: Do you mean optotriac side or LED side? There is no diac there.

Comment: Writet DIAC side.

Comment: There is no DIAC.

Comment: What do you call it then? [link](https://www.google.dk/search?q=moc3021&safe=off&biw=1482&bih=858&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=faKJVZLeCsmosAGX0oD4Cw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=JXdFBQhTVA89LM%253A%3BHqx-8l0X4Z_d1M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fus.100y.com.tw%252Fproduct_jpg_original%252FA011597.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fus.100y.com.tw%252Fchanpin.asp%253Fmno%253D8070%3B640%3B573)

Comment: The left side is a LED. The right side is an optotriac.

Comment: Nice, Null :) and thank you, although my language is not English, I do what I can to make it understandable, and eventually when I learned how text edit works like you here have shown, I will try to improve it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter sentences and more white space, please.

It's really an opto-triac in the MOC3021 (a low current triac). A triac will break over like a diac, but the voltage is not controlled and it's not usually very low as for a diac. In this case, it's only guaranteed to be greater than 400V (VDRM).

The current ITSM is *peak* current, not continuous current. When the opto-triac is used in its typical application it will be driving a much larger triac. When you switch the LED on near the peak of a cycle, the current may only be limited by a single resistor. The triac gate will have very little voltage across it, so the peak current before the triac turns on could be \$\sqrt{2}\times\$ Vrms/R, so for a 240VAC mains, the resistor must be at least 340 ohms to limit the peak current to 1A.

Power dissipation is another (mostly orthogonal) constraint. Normally the power dissipation due to the opto-triac is not very high since it's only short pulses of (typically) some tens of mA near the zero crossing of each cycle. If you try to control a load directly (which is generally not recommended) the power dissipation spec (including LED power dissipation) may come into play. If the current is 100mA RMS and it drops 2V then the power dissipation will be 200mW plus (say) another 50mW for the LED, then the absolute maximum limit will be exceeded for a temperature of only 43°C, which would normally be unacceptable.

Comment: I will keep att in mind! Then I better under the condition det made me more confused.

"it's only guaranteed to be Greater than 400V (VDRM)." Do you mean det kan act a voltage up to 400 Vdrm or att det skal over 400 Vdrm on out når active?

Comment: I have also experienced a problem with att resistance burns, Require large watt, even if we say 6.8Kohm vil Require 17watt. During trials a 2.2 Kohm resistance burns to 0%/off, otherwise Page only warm.

Run it through the op amp regulert out from sawtooth mellom zeros. Do I under stand it right att Vrms-Vout / Iout = R? and if the the opto is kept constant two be on som skal Vrms-Vout / IH = R?

Comment: Sorry this is pretty incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Ok, now I do not know what, but this  338V - 2V (Vgt) / 50mA (Igt) = 6.8 Kohm? and if the the the opto is kept constant on 338V - 2V (Vgt) / 100uA = 3.3 Mohm?

Comment: You don't want the triac to just trigger at the peaks- that means half power and lots of EMI. Series R should be loooooow.

Comment: Yes remembered it yesterday after I signed off, Forgets all the time AC (√2×Vrms) is not DC, thank you :)